# Loading Pandas Data Frame into Excel using writer.save() and getting indexing error

Tags: excel, pandas

I am aggregating a Pandas DF using numpy size and then want to load the results into an Excel using writer.save.  But I am getting the following error:  ***NotImplementedError: Writing as Excel with a MultiIndex is not yet implemented.***

My data looks something like this:

```
agt_id     unique_id
abc123     ab12345
abc123     cd23456
abc123     de34567
xyz987     ef45678
xyz987     fg56789
```

My results should look like:

```
agt_id     unique_id
abc123     3
xyz987     2
```

This is an example of my code:

```
df_agtvol = df_agt.groupby('agt_id').agg({'unique_id':[np.size]})
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(outfilepath, engine='xlsxwriter') 
df_agtvol.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='agt_vols')
```

I have tried to reset the index by using:

```
df_agt_vol_final = df_agtvol.set_index([df_agtvol.index, 'agt_id'], inplace=True)
```

based on some research, but am getting a completely different error.

I am relatively new to working with Pandas dataframes, so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a MultiIndex. The reason you get one is because `np.size` is wrapped in a list.

Although not [explicitly documented](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html), `Pandas` interprets everything in the list as a subindex for `'unique_id'`. This use case falls under the "nested dict of names -> dicts of functions" case in the linked documentation.

So

```
df_agtvol = df_agt.groupby('agt_id').agg({'unique_id':[np.size]})
```

Should be

```
df_agtvol = df_agt.groupby('agt_id').agg({'unique_id': np.size})
```

This is still overly complicated and you can get the same results with a call to the `count` method.

```
df_agtvol = df_agt.groupby('agt_id').count()
```

Comment: Thanks!!  This is perfect.  As a novice, I sometimes make things more complicated than they need to be.